# Creating JSPs with JspWriter?

Tags: jsp, dynamic, printwriter

I would like to generate JSP, depending on how many entries a user has written. For example, I'd like to display 3 entries per page, if the user types in more, two JSPs should be generated. I was wondering whether I can use JSPWriter in the same manner as PrintWriter, to generate JSPs just like HTML pages with PrintWriter?
If not, is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that. JSPs are executed at server-side. Sending JSP markup to the browser doesn't make sense.

If you want to display the three last posts of a user, just select these three last posts from the database and display them. If you want the user to be able to display the next 3 posts, then add a link with parameters to the page. When handling the request, extract these parameters to know which posts to display, get the posts from the database, and display the posts. The whole point of web applications is to be able to generate HTML dynamically, based on parameters coming from the user. You shouldn't generate static pages.

Example of a link to show the posts 3 to 5 of a user:

```
<a href="/posts?userId=1234&amp;start=3&amp;size=3">Next 3 posts</a>
```